# How to install twitter4j package(java) alternative in python?

Tags: python, twitter, paging, twitter4j

Please help. I am new to python. I want to retrive tweets from user timeline.I used the following code.

```
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name = user.screen_name,count = 500)
```

How ever I notice that it retrives only 200 tweets from first page of twitter timeline. I want 500 tweets. So the code should iterate through 3 pages to give 500 tweets. Is there any function to do so. Please help. Stuck on this for 2 days. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only receive 200 tweets per api call. What you can do is save the oldest tweet id and get tweets older than tweet id you saved. This gets you any number of tweets within total number of tweets limit imposed by twitter

```
#no of tweets you want to request
max_tweets = 500
#make initial request for most recent tweets (200 is the maximum allowed count)
new_tweets = api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=max_tweets)

#save most recent tweets
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)


#save the id of the oldest tweet less one
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
#loop for remaining tweets
while(len(alltweets)<max_tweets):
    alltweets.extend(api.GetUserTimeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=(max_tweets-len(alltweets)),max_id=oldest))
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
```

I have not checked if its working but it should work

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply Sir. but can the demonstartion be for twitter api .. not tweepy ...

Comment: What i mean is instead of using tweepy library can you please provide code for twitters api.GetUserTimeline function

Comment: @areddy which library are you using? python-twitter lib or do you want to use base url of twitter api

Comment: @areddy i have updated the code using api.GetUserTimeline this should work.

Comment: Yes sir Im using python twitter lib. Please see the change that i have made in question

Comment: Sir I replaced the code. it works fine in gathering the tweets . Will any properties of alltweets alter due to this procedure? because when i looked at alltweets[1].created_at , it throws an error saying missing values

Comment: @areddy no it doesn't change data format. I just ran the code and everything was fine